# How do access a session variable in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, session-variables

I need use the value of a session variable to send it via form to Paypal.
How do I access the value of a session variable in the web form (.aspx)?

Answer (score 0):

Per https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/03sekbw5.aspx:

- C#:

  `string variable = (string)(Session["variable"]);`
- VB:

  `Dim variable as String = CType(Session.Item("variable"), String)`